# Upload File Size Limit: Symfony Admin Generator Module

Tags: php, apache, file, upload, symfony1

I have form created by the admin generator in the backend of a website. It allows the upload of a video to the site.

It works fine but strangely, the upload fails for files of 10mb or over. However, I have not set any file limits in my form.

Are there Symfony/PHP/Apache/web browser settings regarding this type of behaviour that I can look into?

Or is there a way I can inform Symfony that I'd like to permit larger files?

Comment: The answers were absolutely right, it was not a symfony issue at all. I added the line to .htacces to allow larger files for this site only and it is now working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I haven't ever worked with Symfony I expect the problem due to limitations on your Web-Server.

If you have the possibility to edit or add your .htaccess file then the following line of code will probably help you:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
```

the 100M in example is for 100 Megabyte.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that (at a minimum) you update post_max_size to match. See [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/features.file-upload), especially the sections on "Common Pitfalls" and "Error Messages Explained".